# Can't put `&` inside environment?

Tags: environments, xparse

I'm trying to make the following code compile. It does work if I don't put any `&` in my environment, but if I do I get an error:

```
ERROR: Argument of \environment pral  has an extra }
--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.20   \end{align}
```

Sadly I do need to put `&` inside. Any solution?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{pral}{sob}{%
  \Pr\IfValueT{#2}{_{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\substack{#2}}{#2}}}\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}[\,#3\,]\end{alignedat}
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  &
    \begin{pral}[a \leftarrow \{0,1\}]
      % works without the & on the next two lines:
      &\forall x\\
      &a \geq \delta      
    \end{pral}\\
  &\geq \eta
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `b` argument, which should only be used when really necessary.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{pral}{so}
 {%
  \Pr\IfValueT{#2}{_{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\substack{#2}}{#2}}}
  \begin{alignedat}[t]{2}[\,
 }
 {\,]\end{alignedat}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  &
    \begin{pral}[a \leftarrow \{0,1\}]
      &\forall x\\
      &a \geq \delta
    \end{pral}\\
  &\geq \eta
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But could you ellaborate a bit more on why the `b` is an issue here? What should I do if I really need this `b`?

Comment: @tobiasBora The problem is that with the `b` argument type, the `&` are not hidden from the scanner. I see no real need for it, do you?

Comment: I don't think I need any no, I'm just curious to understand. Thanks!